# Single node Microk8s multus master interface cannot be reached

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I have a single node Microk8s with calico.
I have deployed Multus sucessfully and I can create PODs with the 2nd network interface created succesfuly in the pod because can see the interfaces and the IP address correctly assigned. The pods can reach each other on the 2nd interface successfuly but I cannot reach host eno8 ( ip address 10.128.1.244), the multus master interface from the pods. I also cannot reach the pods from outside.

Am new to this kind of deployment and need help to figure out where the problem is?

Thanks.

Here is some details about my environment:

```
ubuntu@test:$ kubectl get nodes
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
test   Ready    <none>   9d    v1.21.4-3+e5758f73ed2a04

Ip a on HOST
ubuntu@test:$ip a
8: eno8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:6c:2c:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.128.1.244/24 brd 10.128.1.255 scope global eno8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3eec:efff:fe6c:2cff/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ubuntu@test:$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i multus
kube-system          kube-multus-ds-amd64-dz42s                1/1     Running   0          175m

Network Deployment:

apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: test-network
spec:
  config: '{
    "cniVersion": "{{ .Values.Multus_cniVersion}}",
    "name": "test-network",
    "type": "{{ .Values.Multus_driverType}}",
    "master": "{{ .Values.Multus_master_interface}}",
    "mode": "{{ .Values.Multus_interface_mode}}",
    "ipam": {
      "type": "{{ .Values.Multus_ipam_type}}",
      "subnet": "{{ .Values.Multus_ipam_subnet}}",
      "rangeStart": "{{ .Values.Multus_ipam_rangeStart}}",
      "rangeEnd": "{{ .Values.Multus_ipam_rangeStop}}",
      "routes": [
        { "dst": "{{ .Values.Multus_defaultRoute}}" }
      ],
      "dns": {"nameservers": ["{{ .Values.Multus_DNS}}"]},
      "gateway": "{{ .Values.Multus_ipam_gw}}"
    }
  }'

Multus_cniVersion: 0.3.1
Multus_driverType: macvlan
Multus_master_interface: eno8
Multus_interface_mode: bridge
Multus_ipam_type: host-local
Multus_ipam_subnet: 10.128.1.0/24
Multus_ipam_rangeStart: 10.128.1.147
Multus_ipam_rangeStop: 10.128.1.156
Multus_defaultRoute: 0.0.0.0/0
Multus_DNS: 10.128.1.1
Multus_ipam_gw: 10.128.1.1

ubuntu@test:$ kubectl get network-attachment-definitions
NAME         AGE
test-network   8m39s

Network description:

ubuntu@test:$ kubectl describe network-attachment-definitions.k8s.cni.cncf.io test-network 
Name:         test-network
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-demo
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
API Version:  k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1
Kind:         NetworkAttachmentDefinition
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-09-24T12:15:08Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-name:
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:config:
    Manager:         Go-http-client
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2021-09-24T12:15:08Z
  Resource Version:  1062851
  Self Link:         /apis/k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1/namespaces/default/network-attachment-definitions/test-network
  UID:               c96f3a0f-b30f-4972-9271-6b2871adf299
Spec:
  Config:  { "cniVersion": "0.3.1", "name": "test-network", "type": "macvlan", "master": "eno8", "mode": "bridge", "ipam": { "type": "host-local", "subnet": "10.128.1.0/24", "rangeStart": "10.128.1.147", "rangeEnd": "10.128.1.156", "routes": [ { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" } ], "dns": {"nameservers": ["10.128.1.1"]}, "gateway": "10.128.1.1" } }
Events:    <none>



ip a in POD

root@test-deployment-6465bdfccc-k2sst:# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0@if505: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 22:a8:17:13:35:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.1.19.149/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20a8:17ff:fe13:3539/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth1@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether de:c1:d7:67:08:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.128.1.149/24 brd 10.128.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dcc1:d7ff:fe67:893/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Ping to eno8 in POD
root@test-deployment-6465bdfccc-g8bd4:# ping 10.128.1.244
PING 10.128.1.244 (10.128.1.244) 56(84) bytes of data.
^X^C
--- 10.128.1.244 ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13313ms

Ping to multus gateway

root@test-deployment-6465bdfccc-k2sst:# ping 10.128.1.1
PING 10.128.1.1 (10.128.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.128.1.149 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.128.1.149 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.128.1.149 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.128.1.149 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.128.1.149 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.128.1.149 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.128.1.1 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 7164ms
pipe 4


Netstat in the POD
root@test-deployment-6465bdfccc-k2sst:# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         169.254.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.128.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
169.254.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0

ip r in the POD
root@test-deployment-6465bdfccc-g8bd4:# ip r
default via 169.254.1.1 dev eth0 
10.128.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.128.1.149 
169.254.1.1 dev eth0 scope link
```

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm that using `ipvlan` solved my issue, however, I had to use `l2` for my mode. Here's my network attachment config:

```
apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: my-ipvlan
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.0",
      "name": "my-ipvlan",
      "type": "ipvlan",
      "master": "eth0",
      "mode": "l2",
      "ipam": {
        "type": "static",
            "addresses": [
            {
                "address": "192.168.49.3/24"
            }
        ]
      }
    }'
```

I'm just using a static IP for now. More information about `ipvlan` can be found here: [CNI ipvlan](https://www.cni.dev/plugins/current/main/ipvlan/)

Key point from this documentation:

> The kernel driver inspects the IP address of each packet when making a decision about which virtual interface should process the packet.

Using this, I was able to resolve addresses of services internal to my K8s cluster (in my case a Kafka cluster) and external addresses using the newly configured interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may stem from the fact that MACVLAN interfaces cannot be reached from the same host's default route interface. Let's say your PC has interface `eth0` with IP `10.0.0.2` and you use MACVLAN to map an interface in a container as a parent interface eth0, or a sub-interface `eth0.1` etc., by using an IP `10.0.0.3`. You won't be able to reach services running on `10.0.0.3` from the same host, but you will from another host. To resolve this, either use IPVLAN in Layer-3 mode to have fully routable plane. Note that you can't do port forwarding to access the container, because MACVLAN separates the communication on lower layers or use a sub interface with trunking mode `802.1q` (but you will need a switch that supports promiscuous mode on the ports to be able to pass VLAN-tagged traffic).